# Deallocating resources through move semantics

Tags: reference, move-semantics, rvalue

I came across codebase, where "moving ownership" through move semantic is used very frequently to deallocate resources. Example:

```
void process_and_free(Foo&& arg) {
  auto local_arg = std::move(arg);
  ...     // Use local_arg
}

void caller() {
  Foo foo;
  process_and_free(std::move(foo));
  ...
}
```

If there are some movable/dynamic resources in `Foo` after calling `process_and_free`, they will be deallocated (they will be moved to `local_arg`, which runs out of scope inside `process_and_free`). So far so good...

However, I was wondering what happens, if `local_arg` is not created:

```
void process(Foo&& arg) {
  ...     // Use arg everywhere
}
```

Will the resources in `Foo` be deallocated in this case as well?

Second question: do you think, is it a good SWE style to use processing methods to deallocate dynamic resources of the passed argument? I was reading that the move semantics does not guarantee moving of dynamic resources: supposedly they *can* be moved but don't have to. Hence, IMHO it *may be* ambiguous in which state `foo` is after `process_and_free` call...

I think for code reader/reviewer it may be more obvious, if the resources are deallocated inside the caller:

```
void caller() {
  {
    Foo foo;
    process_and_free(foo);
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering both questions:

1. Without creating the `local_arg` variable, the resources will **not** be moved, i.e. the `Foo&& arg` argument does not take ownership of the resources during `process(std::move(foo))` call.
2. Because the resources are not moved in the second example, IMHO it looks to me as a bad and confusing coding style. The reason is that looking only at the call `process(std::move(foo))`, the reader doesn't know what happens with `foo` without reviewing also `process` (btw. if `process` is a member method, it can be `const` with the same effect):

```cpp
void process(Foo&& arg) const {
  auto local_arg = std::move(arg);
  ...
}
```